# odoo 8 dynamically enable and disable default filter

Tags: search, view, odoo-8, qweb

i have a question related to default search views.

Suppose i need to dynamically enable or disable a default filters how could i do? I tried this but it's not working:

```
<field name="context">
{
'search_default_not_closed':1,
'search_default_lancement':[('defaultLancement','=', True)]
}
</field>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround ... changing the computed field i was searching on solved the endless loop issue (i was computing value of the same field i was searching on). fell free to improve. So ...

- my search view has a field looks like
- my menu context

  {
          'search_default_not_closed':1,
          'search_default_watingFor': 'Oui'
          }
- my model

  watingFor = fields.Char(string="En attente de", compute="setWaitingForField", search="searchInWaitingFor")
  // duplicated and stored just to search on
  filterUsingWatingFor = fields.Char(string="En attente de", compute="setfilterUsingWatingFor", store=True)

  def searchInWaitingFor(self, operator, value):
      value = self.getUserGroupName()
      return [('filterUsingWatingFor', operator, value)]

Answer (score 0):

The filter in odoo not like that
Can you put all the code
because the default  filter like this

```
<record id="action_..." model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">STAT</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.report</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="sale.view_order_product_tree"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>  
    <field name="context">{'search_default_Product':1}</field>
</record>
```

This simple example in < context > 
{'search_default_Product':1} 
the default is product